# Is data duplication bad in programming (in contrast to database designing)?

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have three classes: `User`, `Conversation` and `Message`:

**Message properties:**

```
User sender;
// Some more
```

**Conversation properties:**

```
List<Message> messages;
List<User> participants;
// Some more
```

I want to show in the program the creator of the conversation.  I wonder if It is bad programming to add a `creator` property to the `Conversation` class, so I could access it easily and the code would become more readable.:

```
List<Message> messages;
List<User> participants;
User creator
{
    get
    {
        return participants[0];
    }
}
// Use of the property:
conversationObj.creator;
// Instead Of:
conversation.participants[0];
```

Is it considered data duplication because I could get it directly from the `participants` property? Or data duplication is wrong only when designing a database?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no data duplication in your example. It's just a helper function, which is a good idea in this case, since it ensures that the assumption "the first participant is the creator" is only specified in one place.

Comment: There can be a meeting scheduled by a person that can't attend.

Comment: @Basilevs - What do you mean?

Comment: Is the List<User> participants private?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The database equivalent of the above code is a View, and different Views to the same data source are not bad in database design.

Comment: I mean that assumption of meeting owner to always be a participant is unusually strong. Consider creator had to take a leave and no longer participates, why is first invitee suddenly an owner?

Comment: @DocBrown - you could write that in an answer. :)

Comment: @Basilevs - Ho, I actually simplify the logic a bit. In the real program, the creator is actually the user who send the first message. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't duplication of data in the sense of denormalization; all it is, is an extra accessor method.

Duplication of data in the sense of denormalization or caching (another way to describe denormalization) would involve an instance field that captures `participant[0]`.

This particular implementation, having an explicit getter and no setter, is not provided with a backing field (automatic by the language or manual by you); the getter code is executed each time.  Therefore it is not duplication of data.

---

I would equate arguments for denormalization in the database to caching in code: it is commonly done for performance, but as @Jörg says, makes the system more error prone now and also for future maintenance.  Further, caching / denormalization have storage costs and computational costs as well.  So, like all optimization, caching / denormalization should be applied when we have measureable tests that demonstrate good understanding of the problem and that the solution results in improvement.

Comment: I would add that there's an extra important factor when considering denormalisation (as opposed to caching in code): data is persistent, and denormalisation can introduce enormous risks of future data corruption, which are extremely difficult to clean up once they occur.  I've suffered too much from bad DB designs decided on by neglecting this factor!!

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't say that there is a definite answer here. In this case, I would definitely agree with that getter, because `conversation.creator` is semantically more meaningful than `conversation.participants[0]` and it helps with writing self-documenting code.

Comment: Thanks. I would wait to see other answers before I choose the best one. Thanks again,

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two questions here:

> Is this data duplication?

No. No data is being duplicated. You are just providing another reference to already existing data. Think of it this way: it doesn't matter if you tell someone the address to your house or you describe the position of your house relative to some landmark, both descriptions still end up at the same house.

> Is data duplication bad?

No. Getting it right is *hard*, which is why it is commonly avoided, but it is not bad.

Have you ever heard of caching? That's data duplication right there. Database indices? Data duplication.

What *is* bad is confusing the provenance of the data.

You may have multiple copies of data, but it should always be clear which is [the authoritative one](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself). (As soon as you have multiple copies of data, you run into all sorts of trouble, such as keeping them in sync, invalidating them if the authoritative copy changes etc. [This is *hard*](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html), but it is not inherently bad. If you have a lazy evening, try reading up on [multi-CPU cache coherency protocols](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) to get a sense of just how *really* hard it is.)